# how to use Special(reserved) characters in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am newbie to haskell.am trying to implement encryption for a given plain text to cipher.here below is my sample code

```
encryptChar :: Int -> Char -> Char
encryptChar shift c
             | canEncrypt c = chr(ord c + wrapshift)
             | isUpper c = c
            where wrapshift = let shift' = shift `mod` 26 
                              in if (wraparound shift' c)
                                 then shift'-26
                                 else shift'
encryptChar _ '0' = '*'
encryptChar _ '1' = '\''
encryptChar _ '2' = '~'
encryptChar _ '3' = '!'
encryptChar _ '4' = '@'
encryptChar _ '5' = '#'
encryptChar _ '6' = '$'
encryptChar _ '7' = '%'
encryptChar _ '8' = '^'
encryptChar _ '9' = '&'
encryptChar _ '?' = ' '
encryptChar _ c = c
```

when my charecter contains a number it has to encrypt with special symbols for example in the above code when my character contains `1` it has to replace with `\` which I found that it's reserved character in haskell.but how can I use these charecters to encrypt ?

Comment: Not in Haskell, this is bascially how strings are escaped. A backslash is `'\\'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: use **`'\\'`**.

Most programming languages use [***escape sequences*** [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences) to represent special characters, and use the backslash as the start of en escape sequence.

The backslash character is then represented as an escaped backslash, so **`'\\'`**.

Like the table in the Wikipedia article says:

> ```
> Escape Sequence   Unicode   Literal Characters placed into string
> \\                U+005C    backslash (\)
> ```

Comment: oooh @willem Thank you so much.actually, I forgot to show my gratitude on your previous answer of my previous question forgive me for that.but your help meant me a lot.a big Thank you once again ..cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

```
Prelude> putStrLn $ "You can generate a backslash like this: \\ (escape sequence) or like this: \x5c (Unicode identifier sequence) or like this: " ++ [toEnum 92] ++ " (Unicode code point)."
You can generate a backslash like this: \ (escape sequence) or like this: \ (Unicode identifier sequence) or like this: \ (Unicode code point).
```